# errors in fizzbuzz in C using String approach?

Tags: c, c-strings, fizzbuzz

So I was trying to solve the FizzBuzz challenge in various languages using the string method to improve the code. I got stuck in C because things work differently here.
This is my code, I'm getting errors, can anyone explain them to me and help to get the correct code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    int i,n;
    char output;
    printf("Enter Range: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        if(i%3==0)
            strcat(output,"Fizz");
        if(i%5==0)
            strcat(output,"Buzz");
        if(output=="\0")
            strcat(output,i);

        printf("\ni");
    }
    printf("\nEnd.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: `output` is a `char` i.e. one character, not a string. None of your strcat calls are good. You should go back to a good C book or tutorial on strings and printing, one of your printfs is suspicious too.

Comment: Your compiler should warn about `char output; ...  strcat(output,"Fizz");` when fully enabled. What compiler are you using?

Comment: GCC. errors:
FizzBuzz_Modified.c:16:18: warning: result of comparison against a string literal is unspecified
(use strncmp instead) [-Wstring-compare]
if(output=="\0")
                 ^ ~~~~
FizzBuzz_Modified.c:17:27: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'int' to parameter of type
'const char *' [-Wint-conversion]
strcat(output,i);
                ^
/usr/include/secure/_string.h:131:33: note: expanded from macro 'strcat'
           __builtin___strcat_chk (dest, __VA_ARGS__, __darwin_obsz (dest))
                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: when I try to run, I get the output as:
i
I
 i

and abort trap:6

Comment: Don't try to run this code until you fix the warnings.  You need pass the address of a character array to `strcat`.  You're not.  So, declare an array, and pass it.  Look at the man page for `strcat`, and fix your arguments.

Comment: You cannot compare string literal with char `if(output=="\0")` is wrong. Try `if(output=='\0')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ashwini Singh

There are some mistakes in your code ,

1) You declared the `output` variable as char datatype & concatenate string in `Fizz/Buzz` in char . so how can be value of string(which is a array of character) placed in character `output`.

2) You are concatenate the integer value `i` with character `output` e.g `strcat(output,i)` . we need to first typecast the integer value `i` in to char/string datatype & then concatenate with `output`.

The condition of the FizzBuzz programs are,

1) If number is multiple of 3 then add Fizz in the resultant string

2) If number is multiple of 5 then add Buzz in the resultant string

3) If number is neither multiple of 3 nor multiple of 5 then add number in the resultant string

**Code :**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
int i,n;
char output[100]=" ";
printf("Enter Range: ");
scanf("%d",&n);
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    char s[] = {'0' + i, '\0'};
    if(i%3==0)
        strcat(output,"Fizz ");
    else if(i%5==0)
        strcat(output,"Buzz ");
    else
        strcat(strcat(output,s)," ");
}
puts(output);
return 0;
}
```

**Output :**

```
Enter Range: 10                                                                  
 1 2 Fizz 4 Buzz Fizz 7 8 Fizz Buzz
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a good solution, I haven't found many other Fizzbuzz solutions in C using strings so here it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  int i, length;
  printf("Length of FizzBuzz: ");
  scanf("%d", &length);
  char output[1000] = " ";
  for (i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
      strcat(output, "Fizz");
    }
    if (i % 5 == 0) {
      strcat(output, "Buzz");
    }
    if ((i % 3 != 0) && (i % 5 != 0)) {
      char istr[50];
      sprintf(istr, "%d", i);
      strcat(output, istr);
    }
    strcat(output, " ");
  }
  strcat(output, "\n");
  printf(output);
  return 0;
}
```

Albeit I'm not generating the size of output dynamically, but 1000 works fine for the usual 100 used in Fizzbuzz.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I would recommend either not asking for the length with the scanf in the example or alternately, dynamically compute the size. If the intent is to keep it simple, code `int length = 100;` so that you know 1000 will be enough. If you want to make it more robust, get input from the user, but you may want to use argc/argv rather than scanf, along with atoi.